# Regex Match % but not \%

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find the right regex for the case where I want to match a '%' but only if it's not preceded by a '\' between quotations.

For example I want this to come back as a match

> Test \" this % matches \" test

But not match

> Test \" this \% doesn't match \" test

Would a regex master be willing to assist me with this?!

Ultimately my goal is to ensure every '%' is escaped when found within quotations.

Edit:
Here's what I have right now

This is currently what I have but definitely isn't correct.

> \".*[%][^\%].*\"

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? A small bit of research should yield an answer to this.

Comment: This is currently what I have but definitely isn't correct.

\".*[%][^\%].*\"

Comment: What would you recommend I use instead then?

Comment: Try experimenting at https://regex101.com. It will explain what each part of your pattern is doing in the top right window.

Comment: Do try and include your code in the original question with an edit. Comments can't format as well.

Comment: I'm on there right now and have been playing around for about 5-10 minutes, regex has always been my weak point.

Comment: Either test things with [debuggex](http://debuggex.com) or you can easily create an automaton to simulate what you want and then compile it to a regex :)

Comment: The pattern you posted is pretty haphazard. Why did you include `\"` at the beginning and end of the pattern? Was it a requirement to match escaped double quotes? Why did you put `[%]` in square brackets? I recommend examining the pattern explanation at regex101 because it looks like your're just taking shots in the dark. `.*[^\\]%.*` will probably do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([^\\]|\\[^%])*
```

It looks like this seems to work in my tests on https://regex101.com/

The sections are `(   [^\\]   |   \\[^%]   )*`

The `()*` means 0 or more of the contained group.

The contained group is *either* `[^\\]` or `\\[^%]`. The first case is "any character that is not a backslash," which include the percent sign. The second case is "a backslash followed by any character that is not a percent sign."

The `[^ ]` operator is "any character except these."